# Best Practice to use Threading in real time projects?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dynamics-crm

I am trying to use Threading in my code, I have used this code in my solution without Threading. 
I am trying to create bulk records in MS CRM. Sometimes the record count goes very high.

```
//Without Threading

foreach (EntityCollection col in RetrieveContactsFromStaticML(ConnectToCrm(),marketingListRecord))
{
  CreateRecordsAgainstContact(_orgService, col, rewardDetails, errorLoger);
}
```

But this is taking too much time to execute. Because every time "CreateRecordsAgainstContact" method gets called, the process waits for this method to execute.

So I decided to use Threading.

```
//With Threading

foreach (EntityCollection col in RetrieveContactsFromStaticML(ConnectToCrm(),marketingListRecord))
{
    var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate ()
{
    CreateRecordsAgainstContact(_orgService, col, rewardDetails,errorLoger);
});

}
```

But I am not sure about: Is this the best way to use threading?

Here is my code:

```
namespace ActivityDistribution
{

    public class Distribution : IDistribution
{
        private static IOrganizationService _orgService = null;
    private static Logger errorLoger = new Logger();

    public void CreateRewardsAndOfferRecords(Guid campaignActivityId)
    {
        RewardsAndOffers rewardDetails = new RewardsAndOffers();
        Entity CampaignActivity = null;
        Entity ParentCampaign = null;
        EntityCollection marketingListCollection = null;
        try
        {
            _orgService = ConnectToCrm();

            #region RewardsAndOffers Details
            CampaignActivity = _orgService.Retrieve("campaignactivity", campaignActivityId, new ColumnSet("subject", "regardingobjectid", "channeltypecode"));
            ParentCampaign = _orgService.Retrieve("campaign", new Guid(((EntityReference)CampaignActivity["regardingobjectid"]).Id.ToString()), new ColumnSet("name", "istemplate", "statuscode", "new_rewardcategory", "new_rewardsubcategory"));
            rewardDetails.CampaignActivity = new EntityReference(CampaignActivity.LogicalName, CampaignActivity.Id);
            rewardDetails.ParentCampaign = new EntityReference(ParentCampaign.LogicalName, ParentCampaign.Id);
            #endregion

            #region Get MarketingList of given Campaign Activity
            QueryExpression queryMarketingList = new QueryExpression("list")
            {
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("query", "listname", "type"),
                LinkEntities =
                {
                    new LinkEntity
                    {
                        JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                        LinkFromAttributeName = "listid",
                        LinkFromEntityName = "list",
                        LinkToAttributeName = "itemid",
                        LinkToEntityName = "campaignactivityitem",
                        LinkEntities =
                        {
                            new LinkEntity
                            {
                                JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                                LinkFromAttributeName = "campaignactivityid",
                                LinkFromEntityName = "campaignactivityitem",
                                LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
                                LinkToEntityName = "campaignactivity",
                                LinkCriteria =
                                {
                                    Conditions =
                                    {
                                        new ConditionExpression("activityid", ConditionOperator.Equal,  rewardDetails.CampaignActivity.Id)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        },

                    }
                }
            };
            marketingListCollection = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(queryMarketingList);
            #endregion

            #region Fetch MarketingList's Contacts and Create Rewards&Offers Redords against MarketingList's Contacts
            if (marketingListCollection.Entities.Count() > 0)
                foreach (var marketingListRecord in marketingListCollection.Entities)
                {
                    //With Threading
                    foreach (EntityCollection col in RetrieveContactsFromStaticML(ConnectToCrm(), marketingListRecord))
                    {
                        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(delegate ()
                        {
                            CreateRecordsAgainstContact(_orgService, col, rewardDetails, errorLoger);
                        });
                    }
                    //Without Threading
                    foreach (EntityCollection col in RetrieveContactsFromStaticML(ConnectToCrm(), marketingListRecord))
                    {
                        CreateRecordsAgainstContact(_orgService, col, rewardDetails, errorLoger);
                    }
                }
            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errorLoger.Log(ex);
        }

    }
    private static IOrganizationService ConnectToCrm()
    {
        IOrganizationService orgService = null;
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = Credentials.UserName;
        credentials.UserName.Password = Credentials.Password;
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri(Credentials.OrganizationService);
        OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, credentials, null);
        proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
        proxy.Timeout = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);
        orgService = (IOrganizationService)proxy;
        return orgService;

    }
    public static IEnumerable<EntityCollection> RetrieveContactsFromStaticML(IOrganizationService service, Entity entity)
    {
        var queryExpression = new QueryExpression()
        {
            Distinct = false,
            EntityName = "contact",
            ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("fullname", "telephone1"),
            LinkEntities =
                {
                    new LinkEntity
                    {
                        JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                        LinkFromAttributeName = "contactid",
                        LinkFromEntityName = "contact",
                        LinkToAttributeName = "entityid",
                        LinkToEntityName = "listmember",
                        LinkEntities =
                        {
                            new LinkEntity
                            {
                                JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                                LinkFromAttributeName = "listid",
                                LinkFromEntityName = "listmember",
                                LinkToAttributeName = "listid",
                                LinkToEntityName = "list",
                                LinkCriteria =
                                {
                                    Conditions =
                                    {
                                        new ConditionExpression("listid", ConditionOperator.Equal, entity.Id)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
        };

        foreach (EntityCollection col in RetrieveMultipleRecords(service, queryExpression))
        {
            yield return col;
        }
    }
    public static IEnumerable<EntityCollection> RetrieveMultipleRecords(IOrganizationService service, QueryExpression queryExpression)
    {
        int fetchCount = 5000;
        int pageNumber = 1;



        queryExpression.PageInfo = new PagingInfo();
        queryExpression.PageInfo.Count = fetchCount;
        queryExpression.PageInfo.PageNumber = pageNumber;
        queryExpression.PageInfo.PagingCookie = null;
        while (true)
        {
            EntityCollection col = new EntityCollection();
            EntityCollection collection = service.RetrieveMultiple(queryExpression);
            if (collection.Entities.Count > 0)
                foreach (Entity e in collection.Entities)
                {
                    col.Entities.Add(e);
                }
            queryExpression.PageInfo.PageNumber++;
            queryExpression.PageInfo.PagingCookie = collection.PagingCookie;

            yield return col;
            if (!collection.MoreRecords)
                yield break;
        }
    }
    public static void CreateRecordsAgainstContact(IOrganizationService service, EntityCollection contactColletion, RewardsAndOffers rewardsAndOffers, Logger errorLoggger)
    {
        var requestWithResults = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
        {
            Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
            {
                ContinueOnError = true,
                ReturnResponses = false
            },
            Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
        };

        int maxRecordExecuteCount = 0;
        int totalRecords = 0;
        foreach (Entity contact in contactColletion.Entities)
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity("new_rewardsandoffers");
            entity["new_campaignactivity"] = rewardsAndOffers.CampaignActivity;
            entity["new_campaign"] = rewardsAndOffers.ParentCampaign;
            entity["new_contact"] = new EntityReference("contact", contact.Id);
            CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest { Target = entity };
            requestWithResults.Requests.Add(createRequest);
            maxRecordExecuteCount++;
            totalRecords++;
            if (maxRecordExecuteCount == 1000 || totalRecords == contactColletion.Entities.Count())
            {
                service.Execute(requestWithResults);
                maxRecordExecuteCount = 0;
                requestWithResults.Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection();
            }
        }
    }
    }
 public class RewardsAndOffers
{
    public EntityReference ParentCampaign { get; set; }
    public EntityReference CampaignActivity { get; set; }
    public OptionSetValue RewardCategory { get; set; }
    public OptionSetValue RewardSubCategory { get; set; }
}
 class Credentials
{
    public static string OrganizationService
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganizationService"].ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"].ToString();
        }
    }

    public static string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/05/07/asynchronous-and-multithreaded-programming-within-vs-using-the-joinabletaskfactory/

Comment: I would move the loop into its own thread and (depending on execution speed) possible make the for loop create its own thread for each iteration. This would free up the main thread to do its other work while the others do theirs.

Comment: @Ortund Can you explain this with a sample code? As the point you want to put here is not clear to me!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: @rahuldesai I can't post an answer, and actually, I should have voted to close the question for the exact reason its been put on hold, but here's what I would do... https://pastebin.com/WTEUPyrP

Answer (score 1):

This will not work. Concurrent executing tasks cannot share the same `IOrganizationService` instance. You need an object pool providing reusable service instances. Limit the number of instances in the pool to a maximum of 10.

I recommend the **Producer Consumer** pattern using a `BlockingCollection<T>` for scheduling the work that needs to be done. (See [Blocking Collection and the Producer-Consumer Problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2010/08/11/blocking-collection-and-the-producer-consumer-problem/).)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use manually created threads and control it's count. In this example there is a common queue which is processed by multiple threads:

```
public class InsertBulkRecordsTask
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Contact> _contactsQueue;

    public void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            var contacts = RetrieveContactsFromStaticML(ConnectToCrm(), marketingListRecord);
            _contactsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<Contact>(contacts);

            var threadsCount = AppConfigReader.ThreadsCount;
            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            for (int i = 0; i < threadsCount; i++)
                threads.Add(new Thread(ProcessContactsQueue) { IsBackground = true });

            threads.ForEach(r => r.Start());
            threads.ForEach(r => r.Join());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: log
        }
    }

    private void ProcessContactsQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_contactsQueue.IsEmpty == false)
            {
                Contact contact;
                if (_contactsQueue.TryDequeue(out contact) && contact != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Save contact
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // TODO: log
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: log
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteMultipleRequest` is meant for bulk operations, I recommend checking it out (and avoid the effort of implementing threading):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863631.aspx

This is the example provided in the MSDN page, it demonstrates multiple Create requests:

```
// Get a reference to the organization service.
using (_serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serverConfig.OrganizationUri, serverConfig.HomeRealmUri,serverConfig.Credentials, serverConfig.DeviceCredentials))
{
    // Enable early-bound type support to add/update entity records required for this sample.
    _serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

    #region Execute Multiple with Results
    // Create an ExecuteMultipleRequest object.
    requestWithResults = new ExecuteMultipleRequest()
    {
        // Assign settings that define execution behavior: continue on error, return responses. 
        Settings = new ExecuteMultipleSettings()
        {
            ContinueOnError = false,
            ReturnResponses = true
        },
        // Create an empty organization request collection.
        Requests = new OrganizationRequestCollection()
    };

    // Create several (local, in memory) entities in a collection. 
    EntityCollection input = GetCollectionOfEntitiesToCreate();

    // Add a CreateRequest for each entity to the request collection.
    foreach (var entity in input.Entities)
    {
        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest { Target = entity };
        requestWithResults.Requests.Add(createRequest);
    }

    // Execute all the requests in the request collection using a single web method call.
    ExecuteMultipleResponse responseWithResults =
        (ExecuteMultipleResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(requestWithResults);
```

The full sample is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863604.aspx

Comment: This will only provide a limited throughput gain.

Comment: If properly coded this approach can achieve ~1million operations per hour against Online, if that's not enough then CRM isn't the right tool for the task...